# Rails Issue with nested_form gem and jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-form-for, raty

I have a nested form and using nested_form gem by ryan bates in which i am using raty stars in the field, the form is given as

```
<%= f.fields_for :round_questions do |question| %>
     <%= question.label :question %>
     <%= question.text_field :question %>

     <div class="star-questions" > </div>
     <%= question.text_field :answer %>

<% end %>

<%= f.link_to_add "Add a Question", :round_questions,
  :class=> 'btn waves-effect waves-light btn-medium custom_btn_gray',:id => "add-fields" %>
```

and the javascript is given as

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.star-questions').raty({

        targetType : 'score',
        targetKeep : true
});

            $(document).on('click', '#add-fields', function(){

                $('.star-questions').raty({
                    targetType : 'score',
                    targetKeep : true
                });
            });
```

the issue is when i click on add a question the previous star rating are going empty , i know why this is happening because i am passing raty function again to all star-question 
please tell me how can i add question preserving the previous star rating

Comment: is that a solution ? i didnt understand

Comment: @nishantvarshney are you sure this is a valid JS ?

Comment: @hawk i have edited the JS please go through it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the following code a try-

```
$(function(){
  $('.star-questions').raty({
        targetType : 'score',
        targetKeep : true
      });

     $(document).on('nested:fieldAdded:round_questions', function(event){
        event.field.find('.star-questions').raty({
          targetType : 'score',
          targetKeep : true
       });
   });
});
```

Comment: i have edited your answer you forgot  qoutes to put , but this logic worked , thank you so much !!